# Use ConfigProperties in a QuarkusTestCallback

Tags: testing, quarkus, eclipse-microprofile-config

For my integration tests, I would like to simplify the oauth security with an annotation and a `QuarkusTestBeforeTestExecutionCallback`, that sets up my RestAssured instance with the necessary oauth access token for a user with desired roles.

Everything would work just fine, the single problem I'm facing is, that I do not get the URL of the Keycloak Devservice into my `QuarkusTestBeforeTestExecutionCallback`, as apparently `@ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url")`, which does work in the `@QuarkusTest` does not work in the callback class. As the callback class is somehow executed in the context of the `@QuarkusTest`, the property should be theoretically somehow accessible I guess.

How can I get a config property, which is available in a `@QuarkusTest` in a QuarkusCallback class?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get the desired ConfigProperty with manual invocation using the classloader of the test object, as following:

```
public class MyCallback implements QuarkusTestBeforeEachCallback {
    @Override
    public void beforeEach(QuarkusTestMethodContext context) {
        ClassLoader classloader = context.getTestInstance().getClass().getClassLoader();
        Config config = ConfigProvider.getConfig(classLoader);
        ConfigValue configValue = config.getConfigValue("my.config.property.name");
    ...
}
```